# クラスを使った例外処理

Tags: c++

このような関数を書いた場合、どのようにmain関数でtry、catchすればいいのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。言語はｃ＋＋です。クラスを補足しました。説明不足ですみません。

```
template <class T>class DynArray {
    T* pData;
    int size;　public:
    DynArray() {
        pData = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    DynArray(const DynArray& theOther) {
        size = 0;
        pData = NULL;
        this = theOther;
    }

    ~DynArray() {
        if (pData != NULL)
            delete[] pData;
    }

    void InsertAt(const T& newElement, int position);
    void RemoveAt(int position);
};

template<class T>void DynArray<T>::RemoveAt(int position) {
    if (position > size)
        throw new length_error("Position out of the size of DynArray");

    if (size == 1) {
        delete[] pData;
        size = 0;
        return;
    }
    size--;

    T* pTemp = new T[size];

    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++, j++) {
            if (j == position) {
                j--; continue;
            }
            pTemp[i] = pData[j];
        }
    }

    delete[] pData;
    pData = pTemp;

}
```

Comment: `catch`できないとのことですが、言語依存ではなく環境依存の問題が考えられます。使用された環境やコンパイルオプションなどを明示してください。

Comment: また実際に記述したコードと期待する結果、コンパイラーの警告やデバッガーを使わなかった場合の挙動など。「デバッグエラー」についてもどのようなメッセージなのか、など質問する以上は第三者に伝える努力をしてください。

Answer (score 2):

`new length_error`で作られるのは`length_error*`なので

```
try{
}
catch(length_error* le){
}
```

とすることはできます。ただし、`catch`しなかった場合や`catch(...)`とした場合に`delete`する機会がなくなる点、更にはメモリ不足で`new`に失敗する可能性がある点を踏まえて

```
if (position > size)
  throw length_error("Position out of the size of DynArray");
```

と`new`しないことをお勧めします。